# Android Studio can't build apk

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I can not build the apk and I can not run the code in emulator I don't know why but It doesn't work please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The version number is the version of the JRE that the class file is compatible with (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) for more info).  Version 52 is Java 8 so you need to make sure you have a Java 8 JDK installed and that Android Studio is using it.

Instructions on setting your JDK up in Android Studio can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk).